# Use "sed" to Remove Capture Group 1 From All Lines In a File

Tags: regex, sed

I currently have a file with lines like the below:

```
ABCD123RTY,steve_tyler@gmail.com,10.20.30.142,2021-08-20T14:49:51.035Z
ABCD123QWE,thisguy@hotmail.com,10.20.30.245,2021-08-20T14:10:22.254Z
ABCD123DFG,calvin_hobbes2@netnet,10.20.30.l6,2021-08-20T15:30:34.480Z
```

My goal is to remove everything from the "@" to the next comma, such that it instead looks like the below:

```
ABCD123RTY,steve_tyler,10.20.30.142,2021-08-20T14:49:51.035Z
ABCD123QWE,thisguy,10.20.30.245,2021-08-20T14:10:22.254Z
ABCD123DFG,calvin_hobbes2,10.20.30.l6,2021-08-20T15:30:34.480Z
```

I'm not that experienced with utilizing sed and RegEx expressions. In playing around on a testing website, I came up with the below RegEx string, in which capture group 1 is perfectly matching to what I want to remove:
[regex101.com Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX7L8.png)

How would I go about putting this in a "sed" command against a given input file, and writing the results to a new output file. I had tried the below most recently:

```
sed 's/(@.+?),//' input.csv > input_Corrected.csv
```

Just as another note, I'm doing this in a bash script in which I have an API call generating the "input.csv" file, and then want to run this sed command to clean up the data format to match my needs.

Comment: Since the answers don't mention it, I'll add it as a comment here: non-greedy matching (`.+?`) requires Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE), but sed only supports Basic/Extended regular expressions (BRE/ERE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed 's/@[^,]*,/,/' input.csv > input_Corrected.csv
sed 's/@[^,]*//' input.csv > input_Corrected.csv
```

The `@[^,]*,` POSIX BRE pattern matches a `@` and then any zero or more chars other than `,` and then a `,` (in the first example, use it if there MUST be a comma after the match) and replaces with a comma (in the first example, keep the replacement empty if you use the second approach).

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/LPkyHf):

```sh
s='ABCD123RTY,steve_tyler@gmail.com,10.20.30.142,2021-08-20T14:49:51.035Z
ABCD123QWE,thisguy@hotmail.com,10.20.30.245,2021-08-20T14:10:22.254Z
ABCD123DFG,calvin_hobbes2@netnet,10.20.30.l6,2021-08-20T15:30:34.480Z'
sed 's/@[^,]*,/,/' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
ABCD123RTY,steve_tyler,10.20.30.142,2021-08-20T14:49:51.035Z
ABCD123QWE,thisguy,10.20.30.245,2021-08-20T14:10:22.254Z
ABCD123DFG,calvin_hobbes2,10.20.30.l6,2021-08-20T15:30:34.480Z
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! The first solution looks to have worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can used the below regular expression in order to remove the content of the valid email address only.

```
sed "s/@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})//g" input.csv > input_Corrected.csv
```

And as per your requirement you can use the below code. As it is going to replace all the email address on the file as you have on your file "calvin_hobbes2@netnet" which is not valid email address.

```
sed "s/@[^,]*//g" input.csv > input_Corrected.csv
```